# JQuery multi-navigation menu issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, multi-level

Right now I am trying to create a menu just like Microsoft.com, but I am having some issues with my code. The first issue is that when I click a tab to make it active, it works, but when I accordion the subnav back up the active class stays? Then, when I shrink down to a media query, the old subnavs still show up if it is open on desktop version.

Here is a link to view it on JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cheyneosy_/67Ptw/)

Below, is the main JQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#one").click(function (e){
$(".innerMenu2").slideUp(0);    
$(".innerMenu3").slideUp(0);
$(".innerMenu4").slideUp(0);
$(".innerMenu5").slideUp(0);        
$(".innerMenu").slideToggle("fast");
});

$("#two").click(function (e){
$(".innerMenu3").slideUp(0);    
$(".innerMenu4").slideUp(0);
$(".innerMenu5").slideUp(0);
$(".innerMenu").slideUp(0);     
$(".innerMenu2").slideToggle("fast");
e.preventDefault();
});

$("#three").click(function (e){
$(".innerMenu4").slideUp(0);    
$(".innerMenu5").slideUp(0);
$(".innerMenu").slideUp(0);
$(".innerMenu2").slideUp(0);        
$(".innerMenu3").slideToggle("fast");
e.preventDefault();
});

$("#four").click(function (e){
$(".innerMenu5").slideUp(0);    
$(".innerMenu").slideUp(0);
$(".innerMenu2").slideUp(0);
$(".innerMenu3").slideUp(0);        
$(".innerMenu4").slideToggle("fast");
e.preventDefault();
});

$("#five").click(function (e){  
$(".innerMenu").slideUp(0); 
$(".innerMenu2").slideUp(0);
$(".innerMenu3").slideUp(0);
$(".innerMenu4").slideUp(0);        
$(".innerMenu5").slideToggle("fast");
});

/* Mobile Navigation Menu */
$("#mobileLink").click(function (e){
$(".mobileInner2").slideUp(0);  
$(".mobileInner3").slideUp(0);
$(".mobileInner4").slideUp(0);
$(".mobileInner5").slideUp(0);      
$(".mobileInner").slideToggle("fast");
});

$("#mobileLink2").click(function (e){
$(".mobileInner3").slideUp(0);  
$(".mobileInner4").slideUp(0);
$(".mobileInner5").slideUp(0);
$(".mobileInner1").slideUp(0);      
$(".mobileInner2").slideToggle("fast");
});

$("#mobileLink3").click(function (e){
$(".mobileInner4").slideUp(0);  
$(".mobileInner5").slideUp(0);
$(".mobileInner1").slideUp(0);
$(".mobileInner2").slideUp(0);      
$(".mobileInner3").slideToggle("fast");
});

$("#mobileLink4").click(function (e){
$(".mobileInner5").slideUp(0);  
$(".mobileInner1").slideUp(0);
$(".mobileInner2").slideUp(0);
$(".mobileInner3").slideUp(0);      
$(".mobileInner4").slideToggle("fast");
});

$("#mobileLink5").click(function (e){
$(".mobileInner1").slideUp(0);  
$(".mobileInner2").slideUp(0);
$(".mobileInner3").slideUp(0);
$(".mobileInner4").slideUp(0);      
$(".mobileInner5").slideToggle("fast");
});
});


/* Function that toggles active classes for the navigation tabs */
$(function () {
$('.navigation ul li').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).closest('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
 });
});
```

Comment: jQuery selectors work like CSS selectors. You can combine elements into one: `$('.innerMenu2, .innerMenu3, .innerMenu4, ...').slideUp(0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `.addClass()` with `toggleClass()`.

This should do what you need:

```
$(this).closest('li').toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
```